# access running JVM raw memory

Tags: java, jvm, memory-dump

Forgive me if this is an ignorant question, I'm not exactly an expert programmer just curious. Is it possible to read the working memory, say for an instance of a class, from inside a running program?

I know you can do something like `println(theInstance.getClass());` and it will give you the memory address of the instance (I'm assuming thats what it is). I'm wondering if can do something like `byte[]memory = theInstance.getClass().getMemory(); println(toString(memory));` I know thats all made up but just to illustrate.

Comment: It might be possible.  But I don't think it would do you much good. This would be the virtual memory address.  So it's only relevant inside that JVM -- that process really.

Comment: the reason an address is not very useful is that objects can move when the gc is performed. Basicly you don't need to know this level of information in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I didn't have any specific uses in mind, just wondered if it was possible. 

I just realized I was thinking about printing an array. When I do println() on an array with a class instance in it I get an address looking thing after an @ like so:

[0] sketch_dec03a$MyClass@141fab6

Thats from Processing (processing.org) by the way through which I get all my Java experience.

Answer (score 3):

Not using standard Java APIs. However, you can access memory through `sun.misc.Unsafe` (you will probably need to use reflection to get the instance of this class). You can, of course, also do this through JNI.

But why would you want to?

Comment: @Tom - actually, I don't think that JNI does allow you to get at the raw memory per se.  Rather, it provides methods for getting and setting (for example) an object's fields.  (If you knew what the internal representation of a JNI FieldID was, maybe you could "punch" through the abstraction barrier ...)

Answer (score 2):

No, printing the result of getClass() doesn't give a "memory address"; it gives a string representation of a class (which would be something like "class Argyle").

It's not clear, from your question, what you'd expect the contents of such a thing to be. If you'd like to understand how Java represents objects in memory, then read the [VM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html). Then again, [the Java virtual machine does not mandate any particular internal structure for objects](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#16066).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at this lately but if on Linux you could seek/read `/proc/PID/mem`.